# Reorder a list minimizing the total "distance". Can this unknown problem be reduced to known NP-complete problems?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, np-complete

Working on a pet project I stumbled across an (at least to me) unknown problem which I am not able to reduce to already known and well studied combinatorial problems such as Knapsack or TSP. My gut tells me this problem cannot be optimally solved efficiently unless P=NP and greedy approaches do not lead to optimal solutions.

Have you already seen this problem? Do you agree with my intuition? Are you able to reduce it to well studied problems?

#### Definitions

**Tuple**: a set of 3 letters without repetitions, where the order does not matter. For example `<A, B, C>` or `<D, A, G>`. In this context `<A, B, C>` is equal to `<C, B, A>`.

**Lookup table**: a table assigning to each letter a distinct position, where the positions are strictly increasing subsequent numbers. For example:

| Position | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 4 | E |
| 5 | F |

**Distance**: the number of subsequent rows needed to cover a tuple. It describes the distance between the lower and the higher position for all the letters in the tuple for a given lookup table. Different lookup tables yield different distances.

For example using the table above, the tuple `<A,C,B>` has a distance of 3 while the tuple `<B,D,F>` has a distance of 5.

| Position | Letter | Tuple <A,C,B> | Tuple <B,D,F> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | X |  |
| 1 | B | X | X |
| 2 | C | X | - |
| 3 | D |  | X |
| 4 | E |  | - |
| 5 | F |  | X |
| **Distance** |  | **3** | **5** |

#### Problem statement

Given a collection of tuples as input, find the best possible lookup table which minimises the total distance. The total distance is defined as the sum of the distance for each tuple.

#### Analysis

The lookup table has $N!$ possible permutations. Using brute-force it is possible to solve the problem, although not feasible for big instances.

This problem can maybe be attacked using Simulated annealing or similar techniques.

#### Questions

1. How can this problem be approximated with a polynomial algorithm?
2. Can this problem be reduced to well known problems?

Thanks everybody in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the problem via constraint programming as follows.  Rename your letters $A,B,C,\dots$ as $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.  Let integer decision variable $x_i$ represent the position of letter $i$ in the lookup table.  Let $T$ be the set of triples.  For $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}\in T$, let integer decision variable $y_{i_1 i_2 i_3}$ represent the distance.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i_1, i_2, i_3} y_{i_1 i_2 i_3}$ subject to
\begin{align}
&\text{ALLDIFF}(x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}) \\
y_{i_1 i_2 i_3} &\ge x_j - x_k + 1 &&\text{for all $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}\in T$ and $j,k\in\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$} \\
x_i &\in \{0,\dots,n-1\} &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}
For your example with $n=6$ and $T=\{\{0,1,2\},\{1,3,5\}\}$, an optimal solution is
$$x_0=0,x_1=2,x_2=1,x_3=4,x_4=5,x_5=3, y_{0,1,2}=3, y_{1,3,5}=3,$$
with objective value $3+3=6$.

---

I used constraint programming because of ALLDIFF, but you could instead use integer linear programming, with binary decision variables $x_{ip}$ to indicate whether $x_i=p$, where $p\in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$.  The constraints would then be
\begin{align}
\sum_p x_{ip} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\sum_i x_{ip} &= 1 &&\text{for all $p$} \\
y_{i_1 i_2 i_3} &\ge \sum_p p(x_{jp} - x_{kp}) + 1 &&\text{for all $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}\in T$ and $j,k\in\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$} \\
x_{ip} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for all $i$ and $p$}
\end{align}

---

If you had pairs instead of triples, this would be the *minimum linear arrangement  problem*, which is known to be NP-hard. Your problem is a generalization to $3$-uniform hypergraphs.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but is this solvable in polytime?

Comment: Dear RobPratt, thank you a lot for your answer. What is the complexity of your solution? As long as I understand, only instances with a [totally unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Using_total_unimodularity) Matrix can be solved efficiently with the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Dear RobPratt, I temporarily removed the accepted solution check since your answer does not say if the problem can be solved/approximated in polynomial time. In case the above integer linear programming which solves the problem optimally requires exponential time, how is it different from the brute-force solution?

Comment: See my update, which mentions NP-hardness.  Are you interested in theoretical complexity or practical complexity (solving "quickly enough")?

Comment: Hi RobPratt, pardon me, my question was apparently not clear enough. I don’t need an exact solution, an approximation which can be computed quickly is good enough. It is unclear to me what level of approximation can be achieved, but a log or constant factor is fine for my needs.

Comment: @Ciaccia ILP can often find provably optimal solutions quickly, despite the theoretical complexity. How big are the actual instances you want to solve? Do you have sample data you can share?

Comment: @RobPratt again many thanks. I will try to solve the problem exactly with ILP and see how long it takes, I will then update the question with the results and inform you accordingly. In both cases I will add some information about the data that is used. It will likely take some time…